# TravisCI not respecting provided node version

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

I'm working on getting a new project running with TravisCI. The project is hosted on GitHub. I'm working off of a branch, `development`, which is marked as the default branch.

I've got the following `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '4.1'
  - '0.12'
before_install:
  - npm install -g gulp
  - npm install -g jspm
before_script:
  - jspm install
```

and my `package.json` file has:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "test": "gulp test"
},
"engines": { 
  "node": ">=4.1"
},
...
```

I realized that there's a discrepancy between the declared node engine and the `node_js` options in `.travis.yml`. I've done this for testing because my dev environment uses Node 4.1.1, but [TravisCI doesn't list 4.x in its provided versions.](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/#Provided-Node.js-Versions) It does mention 4.x [a little earlier in the docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/#Choosing-Node-versions-to-test-against) though.

Regardless, I'm not seeing 4.x nor 0.12 show up in my build output:

[image]

Have I missed something glaringly obvious or are there other gotchas I should be aware of? I've configured other TravisCI projects to use Node v0.12 without issue and I don't see any difference in my configuration here.

The full project can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/MeoMix/StreamusSocial

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure where the blame lies, but this was definitely an issue outside of my configuration.

I deleted the `.travis.yml` file, pushed the delete to GitHub, created a new `.travis.yml` file and pushed the new file. The issue disappeared.